# Pandas Pivot Table Column with empty value do not show

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I need your help:

I have dataframe d3:

[image: dataframe]

i am using pivot_table

```
df4 = df3.pivot_table(index = ['Number','Department','Task'], columns="Date", values="Score",fill_value = 'N/A')
```

output d4 looks like:

[image]

why is not showing rows where Task empty is.
What i am doing wrong?

I would like to create dataframe like this:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think here is necessary replace misisng values before `pivot_table`:

```
cols = ['Number','Department','Task']
df[cols] = df[cols].fillna('N/A')
```